# Minesweeper Mines wont place or appear

Tags: java, jbutton, minesweeper

Why will this code not load buttons when run? The question is very vague I know but I'm very new to Java and trying to understand lots of things at once. This code is based off of my two previous successful attempts to code TicTacToe and Connect Four both of which worked.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Minesweeper extends Applet implements ActionListener {
    // initializing all data types

    JButton[] a; // The grid boxes
    int counter = 1; // Obsolete
    char[] letter; // Array of mine locations
    int[] numbers; // Array of numbers; values and locations
    boolean explode = false;
    String name1;
    String name2;
    int mines;

    public void init() {
        // The code below initializes and locates the grid
        setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));
        a = new JButton[100];
        // The code below fills the grid with buttons that can be clicked

        for (int counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++) {
            a[counter] = new JButton();
            a[counter].setText(" ");
            a[counter].setBackground(Color.white);
            a[counter].addActionListener(this);
            add(a[counter]);
        }

    }

    public void nit() {

        numbers = new int[100];
        letter = new char[100];
        for (counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++) {
            mines = (int) Math.random() * 100;
            if (letter[mines] == '*') {
                counter--;
            } else {
                letter[mines] = '*';
            }
        } 

        for (counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++) {
            numbers[counter] = 0;
        }

        for (int search = 0; search < 10; search++) {
            for (int searchb = 0; searchb < 10; searchb++) {
                if (letter[search * 10 + searchb] == '*') {
                    if (search != 0) {
                        numbers[((search - 1) * 10) + searchb]++;
                    }
                    if (search != 9) {
                        numbers[((search + 1) * 10) + searchb]++;
                    }
                    if (searchb != 0) {
                        numbers[((search * 10) + searchb) - 1]++;
                    }
                    if (searchb != 9) {
                        numbers[((search * 10) + searchb) + 1]++;
                    }
                    if ((search != 0) && (searchb != 0)) {
                        numbers[(((search - 1) * 10) + searchb) - 1]++;
                    }
                    if ((search != 9) && (searchb != 9)) {
                        numbers[(((search + 1) * 10) + searchb) + 1]++;
                    }
                    if ((search != 0) && (searchb != 9)) {
                        numbers[(((search - 1) * 10) + searchb) + 1]++;
                    }
                    if ((search != 9) && (searchb != 0)) {
                        numbers[(((search + 1) * 10) + searchb) - 1]++;
                    }

                }

            }

        }
        for (int counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++) {
            letter[counter] = (char) ('0' + numbers[counter]);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " " + letter[counter]);
        }
    }

    // ActionEvent e is the click
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int pickedsquare = 0, coloring, pickedcolumn = 0;
        JButton b = (JButton) e.getSource();
        counter++;
        b.setText("Test");
        for (int f = 0; f < 100; f++) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " " + letter[f]);
            if (a[f].getText() == "Test") {
                pickedsquare = f;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " " + letter[f]);
                name1 = " " + letter[pickedsquare];
                a[f].setText(name1);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (letter[pickedsquare] == '*')
            explode = true;

        if (explode == true) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are dead!");
            for (int counterb = 0; counterb <= 99; counterb++) {
                a[counterb].setEnabled(false);

            }
        }

        if (counter == 89) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have swept all mines!");
            for (int counterb = 0; counterb <= 99; counterb++) {
                a[counterb].setEnabled(false);

            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Yes, thats the name for my second method, not very meaningful naming but the Jbuttons wouldn't even appear if it was included in the first method. Not 100% sure why, trying to understand now

Comment: right now are your JButtons appearing? I was under the impression that they werent

Comment: JButtons are appearing now, I moved the letter array to the second method and they appeared. Not sure why that made a difference.
Problem now is that the jButtons simply have "test" written on them when clicked, nothing more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since operands of operators are evaluated from [left to right](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7), the integer cast is occurring first in this statement

```
mines = (int) Math.random()*100;
```

causing the first term to be cast to `0`. This causes `counter` to be decremented as soon as it is incremented resulting in the loop repeating itself *ad infinitum*. Enclose the operands in parenthesis:

```
mines = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
```

Comment: Implemented that code, didn't see a noticeable difference and same issues are occuring

Comment: You removed the loop completely from the `init` method where the problem existed. Now the answer does not relate to the modified code from the question

Comment: Implemented that fixed some other problems and now the game is working, thanks very much for your time